# Import CSV to localhost error on import

Tags: mysql, csv, powershell

I am having some issues with an error message that keeps coming up and I cannot locate why.

I am trying to build a process that utilises the database functionalities of WAMP on my PC to store and manipulate data rather than use MS Access.

The script below contains the current powershell script that I have been working on which is creating a new database and table to contain my CSV data however when I am trying to insert the CSV data into the newly created table it is presenting me with two repetitive errors.

> The property 'CommandText' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

And

> Cannot convert value ",'" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

I am simply at a loss to how to correct this and why it is throwing errors, is this obvious to anyone?

```
$CL2Location = 'L:\Controls\BROKER CASH RECONCILIATIONS\cl2cashpositions-331-Corrected.csv'
$dbnameone = "brokerreconciliation"

[system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$mysqlConn = New-Object -TypeName MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$mysqlConn.ConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=brokerreconciliation;UID=root;PWD=''"
$mysqlConn.Open()

$ccmd = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$ccmd.Connection = $mysqlConn
$ccmd.CommandText = "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS " + $dbnameone
$ccmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$ccmd.CommandText = 'CREATE SCHEMA `' + $dbnameone + '`'
$ccmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$dbonetablescript = @"
    CREATE TABLE brokerreconciliation.CL2 (
    `ID` MEDIUMINT(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `CL2ACCOUNTCODE` varchar(255) default NULL,
    `ACBALANCE` varchar(255) default NULL,
    `PARNAME1` varchar(255) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
    ) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
"@

$ccmd.CommandText = $dbonetablescript
$ccmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$ccmd = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$ccmd.Connection = $mysqlConn
$ccmd.CommandText = "truncate table " + $dbnameone + ".CL2;"
$ccmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
foreach ($i in Import-Csv $cl2location) {
   $cmd.CommandText = 
       "INSERT INTO customers (id,cl2accountcode,acbalance,parname1) VALUES ("
       +$i.id+",'"+$i.cl2accountcode+"','"+$i.acbalance+"','"+$i.parname+"');" 
   $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
}

Import-Csv $CL2Location  ##Added to ensure that the data file was being reached it is

$mysqlConn.Close()
```

Link to example CSV data is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxIeBNzeWg_vTlhiOWVWSWRJUmM).

Trying to resolve this problem I have tried to write the data directly from the data table created via the initial sql query to reduce the amount of steps that I would require.  The code below is the update, even utilising the result set directly I am still hitting the same errors when I try to upload the data to local host.

I have also edited the `CREATE TABLE` element to match the schema of the base database exactly to ensure there was nothing with this that was causing the issue.

I am still at a loss as to how I cannot pass the information from either CSV or script to a newly created table on localhost.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Sql.Data")
$null = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("WindowsBase")

#####################
## - CREDENTIALS - ##
#####################

$MISA = 'xx.xx.x.xx'

$userName = 'IR'
$PassWord = 'IR'
$DB = 'IR'
$timeout = 0

###### - StopWatch - ######

$timeout2 = new-timespan -Minutes 5
$sw = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()

##### sql ####

###  MIS CL2 ### 

$CL2CashPositionsScript = @'
SELECT CL2ACCOUNTCODE, sum(CAST(CL2ACCOUNTBALANCE AS MONEY)) AS CBALANCE, PARNAME1
FROM T5CASHL2 CL2 LEFT OUTER JOIN T5PARTICIPANT PAR
 ON PAR.PARPDRPARTICIPANTID = CL2.CL2ACCOUNTCODE

WHERE CL2CLIENTNUM not like '315'
--AND CL2ACCOUNTCODE = '331'

GROUP BY CL2ACCOUNTCODE, PARNAME1, PARNAME2
ORDER BY CL2ACCOUNTCODE ASC
'@

## CREATE MIS CREDENTIALS ##
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Connection Timeout=0")
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$MISA;Initial Catalog=$DB;
Initial Catalog=$DB;User ID=$userName;Password=$PassWord;"

## - Runs Script from Set Location

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
$SqlCmd.CommandTimeout=$timeout;
$SqlCMD.CommandText = $CL2CashPositionsScript;
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection;

## - Extract Data and build sql data object

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd;
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet);
$DataSetTable = $DataSet.Tables["Table"];

#######

$CL2Location = 'L:\Controls\BROKER CASH RECONCILIATIONS\cl2cashpositions-331-Correctedb.csv'
$dbnameone = "brokerreconciliation"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$mysqlConn = New-Object -TypeName MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$mysqlConn.ConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=brokerreconciliation;UID=root;PWD=''"
$mysqlConn.Open()

$ccmd = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$ccmd.Connection = $mysqlConn
$ccmd.CommandText = "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS " + $dbnameone
$ccmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$ccmd.CommandText = 'CREATE SCHEMA `' + $dbnameone + '`'
$ccmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$dbonetablescript = @"
    CREATE TABLE brokerreconciliation.CL2 (
    `ID` MEDIUMINT(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `CL2ACCOUNTCODE` char(12) default NULL,
    `CBALANCE` char(20) default NULL,
    `PARNAME1` varchar(30) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
    ) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
"@

$ccmd.CommandText = $dbonetablescript
$ccmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$ccmd = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$ccmd.Connection = $mysqlConn
$ccmd.CommandText = "truncate table " + $dbnameone + ".CL2;"
$ccmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
foreach ($i in $DataSetTable) {
   $ccmd.CommandText = 
       "INSERT INTO customers (cl2accountcode,cbalance,parname1) VALUES ("
        +$i.cl2accountcode+"';'"+$i.cbalance+"';'"+$i.parname+"');"
   $ccmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
}

$mysqlConn.Close()
```

Comment: In the `foreach($i in Import-Csv $cl2location)` block, you spelled `$cmd` with a missing `c`

Comment: The variable name should be `$ccmd`, not just `$cmd`. Also, you may want to [import the CSV directly](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) instead of doing multiple inserts.

Comment: Hi Guys, yes I had noticed the $ccmd error and updated it, however same errors persist even with the update.   I have tried formatting the csv in various ways but it is refusing to insert.

Comment: I have tried reformatting the CSV's with pipe and tab

Comment: The first error should have gone away after correcting the variable name. The second error is caused by the value you try to assign to `CommandText`. If you want to wrap a string concatenation statement without escaping the linebreak you need to put the concatenation operator (`+`) at the end of the line, not the beginning of the next line. The way you wrote your code PowerShell interprets `"INSERT INTO ..."` and `+$i.id+",'"+...` as two separate statements.

Comment: I maybe missing something obvious and I think you are correct that the first error has gone away, I wrapped the Command Text syntax as     foreach ($i in $DataSetTable) {
   $ccmd.CommandText = @"
       INSERT INTO customers (cl2accountcode,cbalance,parname1)
       VALUES ("
        +$i.cl2accountcode+"';'"+$i.cbalance+"';'"+$i.parname+"');"
"@

Comment: yet still no cigar...  Cannot fathom it

Comment: That is utterly broken syntax. Remvoe `@"` and `"@`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121545/discussion-between-mr-deans-and-ansgar-wiechers).

Answer (score 1):

You can't wrap strings like this:

> ```
> $ccmd.CommandText = 
>     "INSERT INTO customers (cl2accountcode,cbalance,parname1) VALUES ("
>     +$i.cl2accountcode+"';'"+$i.cbalance+"';'"+$i.parname+"');"
> ```

PowerShell will interpret

```
$ccmd.CommandText = 
    "INSERT INTO customers (cl2accountcode,cbalance,parname1) VALUES ("
```

and

```
+$i.cl2accountcode+"';'"+$i.cbalance+"';'"+$i.parname+"');"
```

as separate statements, because the first two lines are a complete statement in and by themselves. The third line then throws an error, because `+$i.cl2accountcode` (i.e. `$null + [int]`) becomes an integer, and `[int] + [string]` is only valid if the string can be cast to an integer (which is not the case for the string `';'`).

To make string concatenation work across lines you need to either escape the line break

```
$ccmd.CommandText = 
    "INSERT INTO customers (cl2accountcode,cbalance,parname1) VALUES (" `
    +$i.cl2accountcode+"';'"+$i.cbalance+"';'"+$i.parname+"');"
```

or put the concatenation operator at the end of the line (so PowerShell knows there is more to come)

```
$ccmd.CommandText = 
    "INSERT INTO customers (cl2accountcode,cbalance,parname1) VALUES (" +
    $i.cl2accountcode+"';'"+$i.cbalance+"';'"+$i.parname+"');"
```